# Modulo computing without Euler's theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

How would one compute the following congruence without applying Euler's theorem(since it is not possible anyway) and without using calculator?

$2^{1150} \equiv x $ (mod $5^6$)

Comment: I wouldn't say Euler's theorem is _impossible_ to use. But it doesn't help much, no.

Comment: Perhaps $$2^{1150}=(5-1)^{575}\equiv-1+\binom{575}{1}5-\binom{575}{2}5^2+\binom{575}{3}5^3\pmod{5^6}$$ may be helpful...?

Comment: @SangchulLee What happened to $\binom{575}45^4$ and $\binom{575}55^5$?

Comment: @Arthur, I utilized $575=5^2\times23$, which shows $5^2\mid\binom{575}{4}$ and $5\mid\binom{575}{5}$

Comment: Well, Euler's Th. can be of some use here as it does give us the relations: $x = 4 + 5i; ~ x = -1 + 25j; ~ x = -1+125k$, where $x = 2^{1150} \mod 5^6$. All these relations can be easily generated without any need for a calculator (I did it within 2 minutes). You just need Euler's theorem, know basic properties of the totient function and possess  elementary knowledge of group theory, especially group generators and the related tests.